# Renaming .nupkg to .zip

Tags: nuget

We have recently changed our build process to output only .nupkg files and one of our clients doesn't like this idea.I have renamed the .nupkg files to .zip and I can access the files.

My question is... is it acceptable to rename the file extension or will it damage any of the files, compression isn't an issue, so it doesn't matter about that, we just need to be able to give them a .zip version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the contents of a file are not changed when the filename is changed and your files in the .nupkg won't get damaged by renaming it to .zip.